# Keystrokes with gtkmm-3.0

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I've got a project written in c++ using gtkmm 3.0, and I'd like to be able to have the user press a key mapped to a button widget on the screen. I've sifted through 20+ pages of google results with no luck. Anyone know how? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you'd do it in C to make the button click when you press Shift-F1:

```
GtkAccelGroup *accel_group = gtk_accel_group_new ();

gtk_window_add_accel_group (my_window, accel_group);

gtk_widget_add_accelerator (my_button, 
                            "clicked",
                            accel_group,
                            GDK_KEY_F1,
                            GDK_SHIFT_MASK,
                            0);
```